# How to override an ExpansionPanel in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How the title already suggests, I want to have my own ExpansionPanel, where, contrary to the default one, the elevation is set to zero.
I already found this in flutter.dev:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList/ExpansionPanelList.html
I have been trying to implement this but haven't succeeded yet, how do I do it?

So Im talking about these Elevation marks of each ElevationPanel:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but it is as simple as just setting the elevation parameter when you build the widget, as such:

As such:

```
ExpansionPanelList(
  elevation: 0,
  children: [ ... ],
)
```

Edit:

After comments, problem has to do with divider color. Do something like this:

```
ExpansionPanelList(
  dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
  children: [...]
)
```

Comment: it doesn't work, I already tried that. I need to somehow get the ExpansionPanel elevation to zero. When I try to do it over the ExpansionPanelList widget, nothing happens. I will add a picture of what I mean in the question

Comment: Just realised that because of that, the Link that I posted is useless

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "elevation marks". Do you mean the dividers (horizontal lines) you see in that picture?

Comment: Yes, sorry thought these were there because of the elevation

Comment: No, nothing to do with elevation. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, had no Idea how easy it was